# Can I tick a checkbox using BeautifulSoup / Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning to use `Selenium` & `BeautifulSoup` and am struggling with the following:

I have a list of product codes:

`['1242737-011',
'4232345-015',
'5673845-013']`

for which I need to tick the checkbox in the following html code. So in this case only the first checkbox would get selected (1242737-011)

```
<tr class="dividebelow">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1242737-011&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>x small</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>

        <input class="select_products__product_table_1242737_checkbox select_products__variants_checkbox" name="variants" value="11866208" type="checkbox">

    </td>
</tr>

    <tr class="dividebelow">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1242737-012&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>small</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>

        <input class="select_products__product_table_1242737_checkbox select_products__variants_checkbox" name="variants" value="11866209" type="checkbox">

    </td>
</tr>
```

Any idea how this can be done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: posting the url will be helpful

Comment: It's on a private server :(

Comment: if you want to tick checkbox then you have to use Selenium's functions, not BeautifulSoup. Read [Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Eventually you would have to use `requests` to send form to server - without using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

`Selenium` has many functions to search element and click it to check it.

You can use `find_element_by_name(name)` or `find_element_by_xpath(...)` when you want to use complex `xpath`

---

Example code for page with three checkboxes

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox'

#driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# checkboxes are in <iframe> so I have to switch frame
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

# click checkboxes using names
for name in ["vehicle1", "vehicle2", "vehicle3"]:
    items = driver.find_element_by_name(name)
    #items = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//input[@name="{name}"]')
    items.click()

# click "Submit"
#button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Submit"]')
button.click()
```

---

**BTW:** `BeautifulSoup` will be useless because it can't change checkboxes in web browser and click button to sends it to server.